# I want to append JList selected items to Jtextfield

Tags: java, swing

When I Select a value from Jlist, I want to append it to the Jtextfield without replacing existing values,
This is what I tried So far, As you can see this is replacing existing value

```
    jlist.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
            if (!arg0.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                textField.setText(jlist.getSelectedValue());

            }
        }
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Have you tried to obtain a text from the field and modifying the text rather than replacing it?

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying, can you please clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

Clarification:

```
jlist.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
        if (!arg0.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            textField.setText(textField.getText() + jlist.getSelectedValue());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like using the getText() / setText() approach. This will generate inaccurate DocumentEvents. It will generate one event for the removal of all text and then another event for the addition of the existing text and the appended text which is not accurate.

You can update the `Document` of the text field:

```
Document doc = textField.getDocument();
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), jList.getSelectedValue().toString(), null);
```

You will need to wrap the code in a try/catch block.

Or a trick to avoid the try/catch block is to use:

```
textField.setCaretPosition( textField.getDocument().getLength() );
textField.replaceSelection( jList.getSelectedValue().toString() );
```